# Android Post data with CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet

Tags: java, android

I am calling a url by following method

```
try {
            urlcont= URLEncoder.encode(urlcont, "utf-8");

            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("http://www.myurlhere");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

URL called successfully but I want to post some data (in String urlcont ) so i can get it by $_POST['urlcont'];

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "your name"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```